# IntelliJ IDEA can show maven projects like eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

In eclipse i could add any package in classepath and the "Package Explorer" shows these packages in the root of the view. 
I ask, can i do something similar to this in IntelliJ IDEA? Because by default i have to navigate manually to the src/main/java, and i want that folder appear on root of the "Projects View".

Sorry by the english.

Answer (score 5):

Just change the view in [Project Tool Window](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project-tool-window.html#d416728e351) from `Project` view to `Packages` view.

`Project` view:

[image]

`Packages` view:

[image]

Comment: This should help... but i still don't have easy access to the web files... i think the IDEA should have an option which show on root of tree these directories that have the "marked as" flags, like "Sources", "Tests", "Resources"...
But thanks very much, anyway!!